# React Router loads URL in address bar but doesn't load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3r1v).

When a user clicks on a link, it should load the component in '/details'. However on click, it does load /details in the address bar but the component doesn't actually load. It only loads on going separately to /details manually in the address bar.

**Routes.js**

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/details" component={MachineDetail} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

**MachineCard.js**

```
export default function MachineCard({ image, title, weight, power }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <div className="card">
          <Router>
            <Link to="/details">
              <img className="img-fluid" src={image} alt={title} />
              <h2>{title}</h2>
            </Link>
          </Router>
          <p>Operating weight: {weight}</p>
          <p>Power: {power}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any idea why it won't load the '/details' component in the browser?

Comment: You're exporting `MachineCard` from your component and using `MachineDetail` in your router. Is that correct? Maybe post more of your code, including the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that you have multiple routers in your app, but you only need one. Since you already have the router defined in your index file, you can go ahead and remove it from `MachineCard.js`.

Your `MachineCard.js` component can therefore be simplified to this:

```
export default function MachineCard({ image, title, weight, power }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <div className="card">
          <Link to="/details">
            <img className="img-fluid" src={image} alt={title} />
            <h2>{title}</h2>
          </Link>
          <p>Operating weight: {weight}</p>
          <p>Power: {power}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is incorrect naming. In your route files you are using MachineDetail but you are exporting MachineCard.